# Plotly Dropdown not updating graphs correctly

Tags: pandas, drop-down-menu, plotly

I am working on creating dropdown menu for my data
here is my data

```
data = {'Time': [2,4,5,6,7], 'Voltage': [20.3, 17.2,15.3,9.4,2], "Current":[2, 5,7,8,9]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

this is the code for plotting dropdowns

```
plot = px.Figure(data=[go.Scatter( 

    name='Voltage', 

    x=df["Time"], 

    y=df["Voltage"]
), 

    go.Scatter( 

    name='Data 2', 

    x=df["Time"], 

    y=df["Current"] 
) 
]) 

plot.update_layout( 

    updatemenus=[ 

        dict( 
            buttons=list([ 

                dict(label="Voltage", 

                     method="update", 

                     args=[{"visible": [True, False]}, 

                           {"title": "Voltage", 

                            }]), 

                dict(label="Current", 

                     method="update", 

                     args=[{"visible": [False, True]}, 

                           {"title": "Data 2", 

                            }]), 

            ]), 

        ) 

    ]) 
plot.show()
```

even though i am not selecting both plots to display it is showing both plots how to overcome this
thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `visible = False`to second scatter. So it should be :

```
go.Scatter( 

name='Data 2', 

x=df["Time"], 

y=df["Current"] ,

visible = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code defines the two scatter plots as one graph, so if you rewrite it to set up two graphs, the buttons are not set up incorrectly and the graph can be changed by the drop down buttons.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name='Voltage', x=df["Time"], y=df["Voltage"], line_color='blue')) 
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name='Data 2', x=df["Time"],  y=df["Current"], line_color='red'))

fig.update_layout( 
    updatemenus=[ 
        dict( 
            buttons=list([ 
                dict(label="Voltage", 
                     method="update", 
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False]}, 
                           {"title": "Voltage", 
                            }]), 
                dict(label="Current", 
                     method="update", 
                     args=[{"visible": [False, True]}, 
                           {"title": "Data 2", 
                            }]), 
            ]), 

        ) 

    ]) 
fig.show()
```

[image]
[image]